# Get binary image data from postgres database and save in folder

Tags: java, image, postgresql

I want to save all the image in a folder which already saved in database as 
byte array.

After successfully saving 200+ image my code shows error.

Details of my code and error described below :

**Database field type**

```
photograph bytea
```

**Domain Class**

```
private Byte[] photograph
```

What I have tried so far :

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.color.CMMException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException, IOException {

        System.out.println("-------- PostgreSQL "
                + "JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                    + "Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/an?currentSchema=an", "postgres"
                                                + "",
                    "123456");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
                        //start
                        String query = "my_query";
                        PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                        int i=0;
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            i++;
                            System.out.println("Saving ... :  "+i);
                            // convert byte array back to BufferedImage
                        if(null == rs.getString(1)){
                            continue;
                        }    
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes(1));
            BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
                        if(null == bImageFromConvert){
                            continue;
                        }
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("e:/images/"+rs.getString(2)+".jpg");

            ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", out);
                        }
                        //end




        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }





}
```

It works fine until error occurs . How to overcome this problem .
I want to save all images and if i cant then just skip to next image 
thats what I want.

**Error :**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1068)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1039)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:84)
C:\Users\Shifat\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 20 seconds)
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but wouldn't a simple `try { ... } catch { ... }` block around `ImageIO.read()` do the trick?

Comment: Yes. Its working.